# Incremental variable doesn't update array list in angular template

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor, angular-template

I have a 2D array in component TS file and I'm property binding it in my template. When I refresh the page I get 0 index and the list gets displayed properly but when I increment my variable in `onVegetableDrop` function, it doesn't step in array to a next index and don't update my list, although in the console I can see that the variable `i` gets incremented to `1`. Why is so?

Code:

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'angular-draganddrop';

  questions:string[] = ["what is nepal", "what is nepal2", "what is nepal3"];
  correctAns:string[] = ["Carrot", "Onion", "Potato", "Capsicum"];
  i:number = 0;
  score:number = 0;

  vegetables = [[
    {name: 'Carrot', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Onion', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Capsicum', type: 'vegetable'}],
    [
  {name: 'Carrotas', type: 'vegetable'},
  {name: 'Onionas', type: 'vegetable'},
  {name: 'Potatoas', type: 'vegetable'},
  {name: 'Capsicumas', type: 'vegetable'}]]

  onVegetableDrop(e: DropEvent) {

    if(e.dragData.name == this.correctAns[this.i]) {
      console.log("correct");
      this.score++;
    }
    this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.vegetables);
    this.i++;
    console.log(this.i);
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of [vegetables[this.i]]">
    <li
      *ngFor="let items of item"
      class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-success"
      [draggable]
      [dragClass]="'active'"
      [dragTransitClass]="'active'"
      [dragData]="items"
      [dragScope]="items.type"
      [dragEnabled]="dragEnabled">
      {{items.name}}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: your code works fine for me. (except a view issues with unknown properties which you maybe removed to make the example clear?)

Comment: https://angular-n3vc9t.stackblitz.io

Comment: Very weird because for me it doesn't. You implemented on click function, mine is onDrag. No difference here, once I drag and drop and increment the variable, I get no more answers options from array, like `Carrotas` etc..

Comment: Okay, i figured out that this line of code `this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.vegetables);` was removing the index of array and thus it couldn't render the items in view. Not really sure what it does as I'm not that familiar with ng-drag-drop npm module but as it sounds it probably removes item I drag from `vgetables` array and mess it up or something. I just wonder why I was not getting undefined or anything.